# map string spaces to list of words?

Tags: python

I have a string as

```
flagged_line = "V. Divakar Botcha1,2, Mengdie Zhang1, Kuilong Li1,2, Hong Gu1,2, Zhonghui Huang1, Jianhui Cai3, Youming Lu1, Wenjie Yu3, and Xinke Liu1*  "
```

and list of words as

```
words = ['V.', 'Divakar', 'Botcha', '1', ',', '2', ',', 'Mengdie', 'Zhang', '1', ',', 'Kuilong', 'Li', '1', ',', '2', ',', 'Hong', 'Gu', '1', ',', '2', ',', 'Zhonghui', 'Huang', '1', ',', 'Jianhui', 'Cai', '3', ',', 'Youming', 'Lu', '1', ',', 'Wenjie', 'Yu', '3', ',', 'and', 'Xinke', 'Liu', '1', '*']
```

Both of them comes from 2 different programs and now I need to map the spaces from the string to the words in list like: (Note, the trailing spaces after words that ere followed by a space)

```
['V. ', 'Divakar ', 'Botcha', '1', ',', '2', ', ', 'Mengdie ', 'Zhang', '1', ', ', 'Kuilong ', 'Li', '1', ',', '2', ', ', 'Hong ', 'Gu', '1', ',', '2', ', ', 'Zhonghui ', 'Huang', '1', ', ', 'Jianhui ', 'Cai', '3', ', ', 'Youming ', 'Lu', '1', ', ', 'Wenjie ', 'Yu', '3', ', ', 'and ', 'Xinke ', 'Liu', '1', '*  ']
```

What I am trying is to check them char by char and then assigning spaces

```
index_str = 0
for elem in words:
    for e in elem:
        if e == flagged_line[index_str]:
            index_str+=1
            pass
        else:
            index_str+=1
            elem = elem+' '  # issue not generalized for spaces
            print('"',elem,'"')
```

UPDATE:

The list element will have space included to help map like

in string is

```
"V. Divakar  "
```

and the list is

```
['V.','Divakar']
```

then final list should be

```
['V. ','Divakar  ']
```

later I will iterate on the list and append the element to my next function.

there can multiple spaces too at the end

Comment: what would you like the end-product to be? For me its not very clear.

Comment: The problem is unclear. Does the elements in the second list always have to be consumed in the given order? If not, are all elements distinct? (Then why not use a set?)

Comment: The problem is clear, but why would you want that? Why not the list of words already in the required form in the first place?

Comment: @Austin Would you mind explaining ?

Comment: I've got 2 different programs processing one file and i need to map all the words separately with the spaces

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, from what I observe, elements in `words` have to appended by a space if there is a space in `flagged_line` also following that word (just my observation).

Comment: Something like `print(['{0} '.format(x) for x in words])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assumed `flagged_line` and `words` is exactly matched. You can do this by one-pass, just mantain the `index` of `flagged_line`, and jump over the `len(word)` to find if there are spaces after one word, if it has, add to your result:

```
flagged_line = "V. Divakar Botcha1,2, Mengdie Zhang1, Kuilong Li1,2, Hong Gu1,2, Zhonghui Huang1, Jianhui Cai3, Youming Lu1, Wenjie Yu3, and Xinke Liu1*  "
words = ['V.', 'Divakar', 'Botcha', '1', ',', '2', ',', 'Mengdie', 'Zhang', '1', ',', 'Kuilong', 'Li', '1', ',',
         '2', ',', 'Hong', 'Gu', '1', ',', '2', ',', 'Zhonghui', 'Huang', '1', ',', 'Jianhui', 'Cai', '3', ',',
         'Youming', 'Lu', '1', ',', 'Wenjie', 'Yu', '3', ',', 'and', 'Xinke', 'Liu', '1', '*']

words_with_spaces = []
idx = 0
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    idx += len(word)
    cur_word = word
    while idx < len(flagged_line) and flagged_line[idx] == ' ':
        cur_word += ' '
        idx += 1
    words_with_spaces.append(cur_word)

print(words_with_spaces)
```

output:

```
['V. ', 'Divakar ', 'Botcha', '1', ',', '2', ', ', 'Mengdie ', 'Zhang', '1', ', ', 'Kuilong ', 'Li', '1', ',', '2', ', ', 'Hong ', 'Gu', '1', ',', '2', ', ', 'Zhonghui ', 'Huang', '1', ', ', 'Jianhui ', 'Cai', '3', ', ', 'Youming ', 'Lu', '1', ', ', 'Wenjie ', 'Yu', '3', ', ', 'and ', 'Xinke ', 'Liu', '1', '*  ']
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner using `str.find()` to find the substring, if it exists append the space:

```
flagged_line = "V. Divakar Botcha1,2, Mengdie Zhang1, Kuilong Li1,2, Hong Gu1,2, Zhonghui Huang1, Jianhui Cai3, Youming Lu1, Wenjie Yu3, and Xinke Liu1*  "    
words = ['V.', 'Divakar', 'Botcha', '1', ',', '2', ',', 'Mengdie', 'Zhang', '1', ',', 'Kuilong', 'Li', '1', ',', '2', ',', 'Hong', 'Gu', '1', ',', '2', ',', 'Zhonghui', 'Huang', '1', ',', 'Jianhui', 'Cai', '3', ',', 'Youming', 'Lu', '1', ',', 'Wenjie', 'Yu', '3', ',', 'and', 'Xinke', 'Liu', '1', '*']

print(['{0} '.format(x) if flagged_line.find(x + " ") != -1 else x for x in words ])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['V. ', 'Divakar ', 'Botcha', '1', ', ', '2', ', ', 'Mengdie ', 'Zhang', '1', ', ', 'Kuilong ', 'Li', '1', ', ', '2', ', ', 'Hong ', 'Gu', '1', ', ', '2', ', ', 'Zhonghui ', 'Huang', '1', ', ', 'Jianhui ', 'Cai', '3', ', ', 'Youming ', 'Lu', '1', ', ', 'Wenjie ', 'Yu', '3', ', ', 'and ', 'Xinke ', 'Liu', '1', '* ']
```

Comment: This outputs wrong if `flagged_line = "V. Divakar V.Botcha1...` and `words = ['V.', 'Divakar', 'V.', 'Botcha', '1',....]` for example. Because `find` always finds first occurance.

Comment: @Austin The output is exactly how the OP wanted and even the one in the accepted answer, enlighten me if I am missing something?

Comment: Try with my inputs. I believe second `V.` shouldn't contain space at the end in the output.

Comment: Sure, let me counter-check it!

Comment: the output is missing the last 2 spaces in the last element your output only contains the single space